# Merge two lists into dynamic list in Python

Tags: python

I have a scenario where have lists List1 and List2 which has below values

List1 = [1,2,3]

List2 = [(11,22,33),(44,55,66),(77,88,99)]

Expected List3 = [(1,11,22,33),(2,44,55,66),(3,77,88,99)]

I need to populate this List3 in Python.Any help is appriciated.

i tried using multiple for loops but didnt work somehing like this

```
list = [] 
        for id in tIDs:
            tIDy = id["ID"]
            for row in PlanDf[["Owner","SP","rep"]].itertuples(index=False):
                list.append((tIDy ,tuple(row)[0],tuple(row)[1],tuple(row)[2]))
                break
```

Comment: I recommend to research the concept of a "zip" operation ([here is Python's version](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)). That is usually a good start for operations that mix A1 with B1, mix A2 with B2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short one:

```
List3 = [*zip(List1, *zip(*List2))]
```

A fast one:

```
List3 = [(a,) + b for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Benchmark of some solutions with lists 1000 times longer:

```
311 us  [*zip(List1, *zip(*List2))]
281 us  [(a,) + b for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
424 us  [(a, *b) for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVA7boQwFOx9imlWttknBZb9sJG4QW6wogDFq7gwWMYUyeXJs0FRUsWNR/PT0/jP@DGNdePDuj7D5BCtMzbCOj@FiGC86aMQs4mLRwsppXizc6wYPyo6Ud2hQFWWZaZPiVYVC6zUmtT5TJcLXa8MbzdqGrrf9U8ilQkzp4wAP/kovqxXuZ@QcZFbte4k7RbVk8YRA55TQE8M7IhfsS3wx49i0P/bOyGSxyQDH1Wgfs0V4@IGE/hIvjkTkbGzo9q2UYaQ16Hd2W4f7du1Vak1XnYxF/hgx6jkoX7HMkPiABXTJoZngtHr@g0)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = '''
List1 = [1,2,3] * 1000
List2 = [(11,22,33),(44,55,66),(77,88,99)] * 1000
'''

es = [
    '[*zip(List1, *zip(*List2))]',
    '[(a,) + b for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]',
    '[(a, *b) for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]',
]

for e in es * 3:
    number = 100
    t = min(repeat(e, setup, number=number, repeat=10)) / number
    print('%3d us ' % (t * 1e6), e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension like so:

```
List3 = [(i, *lst) for i, lst in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 11, 22, 33), (2, 44, 55, 66), (3, 77, 88, 99)]
```

Full test case:

```
List1 = [1,2,3]
List2 = [(11,22,33),(44,55,66),(77,88,99)]

List3 = [(i, *lst) for i, lst in zip(List1, List2)]

print(List3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

Firstly, do not name your `list` "list". When it comes to concocting the final `list` you simply put your `id`, and **unpacked* vars in a `tuple`.

```
L1 = [id["ID"] for id in tIDs]
L2 = [row for row in PlanDf[["Owner","SP","rep"]].itertuples(index=False)]
L3 = [(a,*b) for a, b in zip(L1, L2)]     

print(L3)
```

Since all this code is specific to you, and without the rest of it I cannot test or prove it, here is a generic example of the same thing.

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [(11,12,13), (21,22,23), (31,32,33)]
L3 = [(a,*b) for a, b in zip(L1, L2)]
    
print(L3)
```